# Place 4 Forms side by side with auto resize

Tags: c#, forms

I have 4 forms and I need that when the software starts, these 4 forms will be automatically placed side by side to fill the entire screen resolution. Also, when one of these is resized, the others automatically have to resize themselves as well.

The expected result is this: [image: here].

Also, is it possible to have all 4 forms in "evidence" like the `Form1` in the example?

Comment: You can try using MDI forms. You will have one parent form and 4 child forms inside of it. In that way it will be much easier to control others. Example here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3553/Introduction-to-MDI-Forms-with-C

Comment: I agree with MDI forms for the placement, but when you really need to move them alongside eachother, i guess split panels and converting forms to user controls would make more sense, then you don't have to write the logic for the resizing. If it doesn't have to be winforms, think about WPF with it's very good sizing techniques and custom controls. And to the second question, no, only one can be the active form, but user controls would give you a way to create all that without using windows

Answer (score 0):

SplitContainers with UserControls makes the most sense to me.  *You can design the layout of the UserControls such that they have a "title" at the top kinda like a Form.

**splitContainer1**, Dock Fill, **Orientation Vertical**, BorderStyle FixedSingle

**splitContainer2** inside Panel1 (left side of splitContainer1), Dock Fill, **Orientation Horizontal**, BorderStyle FixedSingle

**splitContainer3** inside Panel2 (right side of splitContainer1), Dock Fill, **Orientation Horizontal**, BorderStyle FixedSingle

Here's a picture with Labels taking the place of the UserControls:
[image]